# Wordpress custom post_type templates

Tags: wordpress

We are currently working on a Wordpress page that reuses data from another Application. To keep things clean, but still use most wordpress features, we decided to use custom `post_type` settings (`register_post_type`) for this data.

Now the Problem is, that while accessing these *Posts* is no problem, the `Permalink's` to them fail with **404 errors**.

We currently work around this issue by adding an action to the `template_redirect` hook that essentially performs a `query_posts` for the name and our custom types. If `query_posts` found something we load our custom post templates with locate_template.

Although this is working, it does not look like a clean solution - can anyone here propose a better way to tackle our problems?

Comment: How did you add the permalinks to the rewrite rules? Could you post your WP_Rewrite-related code?

Comment: nothing fancy - just classic %year%/%month%/%postname% - is it possible to add post_type to the permalink structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Login to Dashboard and go to Settings -> Permalinks -> Click "Save Changes" without making any changes. This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: sorry, this does not work - i think it hat to do with the fact that wordpress by default only tries to load posts with post_type = 'post' for the permalinks